# To access the list object of outer class in the inner class in python

Tags: python, inner-classes

```
class policy(object):

    def __init__(self,name):

        global policies_list

        self.policy_1_list=[]

        self.id=name

        policies_list.append(self)


    class policy_1:

        def __init__(self):

            policy_1_list.append(self)
```

How to use policy_1_list a list object of the outer class policy in the constructor of the inner class policy_1?
How do I refer it as an outer class element?

Comment: Inner classes are very rare in Python, because they usually aren't needed. What is it about `policy` that requires `policy_1` to be an inner class? One option is to have `policy_1.__init__` take a `policy` object as an argument instead, but it's not clear what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: What is the meaning of the code is irrelevant, but can you write a simple code that contains outer and inner class and try to access  a outer class variable in the any method of the inner class.

Comment: You can't, though. `policy_1_list` is an attribute of an *instance* of `policy`; it's not unique. You have to give `policy_1.__init__` an instance of `policy` first.